# Physics Informed Neural Network for Dynamical Systems. Unexpected Result in my code

Tags: neural-network, differential-equations

I am attempting to use a NN to simulate a dynamical system. You can think of this as a damped oscillator who's position is y and its velocity is y' at a given time instant and f is a force acting on the object. I want to develop a Physics informed NN that will take in input y, y' and f of the previous timestep and output y, y' of the new time step to simulate the dynamical system.

to compute derivative, i first used finite difference method to compute derivative and using that to approximate derivatives and compute the loss. Then for higher epochs, i am using a centered finite different scheme which has greater accuracy and then i am using a 5 point stencil to compute the derivative for maximum accuracy.

The code doesn't seem to work as expected so i was trying different techniques to make the code work.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
def f_train(t):
  Y_TRAIN =  (4*np.sin(t)*np.exp(-0.14*np.abs(t-15)) + 3.5*np.sin((t))*np.sin(1.5*t)*np.exp(-0.2*np.abs(t-110))) + np.sin(0.22 * t) * np.exp(-0.1*np.abs(t-75)) * 2
  return Y_TRAIN

def dY_dt(t,Y):
  x,v = Y
  Y_dot = [v, f_train(t) - v - 4*x]
  return Y_dot

S0 = [0,0.5]

t = np.linspace(0,160,int(1.1e5))
soln = odeint(dY_dt, y0 = S0, t = t, tfirst = True)

plt.plot(t,f_train(t))
plt.title("Forcing Function")
plt.show()

# finding y'':

d2ydt2 = np.gradient(soln.T[1],t)

y_prime = np.gradient(soln.T[1],t)
y_prime = []
y_prime.append(soln.T[0][0])
for i in range(1,len(soln.T[0])):
  y_prime.append(soln.T[0][i] - soln.T[0][i-1])
y_prime = y_prime / (t[2]-t[1])


y_prime2 = [(soln.T[1][1] - soln.T[1][0])]


for i in range(1,len(soln.T[0])):
  y_prime2.append(soln.T[1][i] - soln.T[1][i-1])
y_prime2 = y_prime2 / (t[2]-t[1])
print((y_prime2-d2ydt2))
# Ground Truth:
plt.plot(t,soln.T[0], label = "y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.plot(t,soln.T[1], label = "dy/dt")
plt.plot(t,soln.T[1], label = "y_prime")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(t,d2ydt2, label = "d2y/dt2")
plt.plot(t,y_prime2)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Defining Loss
cost_function = nn.MSELoss()

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Defining NN
neural_solution = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(3, 64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64, 64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(64, 2),
).double().to(device)  # Set the model to use double precision

# Defining the optimization Algorithm
optimizer = optim.Adam(neural_solution.parameters(), lr=0.004)

y_train, dydt_train = soln.T
d2ydt2_train = torch.tensor(d2ydt2).double().to(device)  # Convert to double precision

# These are the tensor inputs to the NN:
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train).double().to(device)  # Convert to double precision
dydt_train = torch.tensor(dydt_train).double().to(device)  # Convert to double precision
force_train = torch.tensor(f_train(t)).double().to(device)  # Convert to double precision

print(len(dydt_train))
print(len(y_train))
print(len(d2ydt2_train))

Loss_array = []
num_epochs = int(400)
delta_t = t[3] - t[2]

scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[int(0.75 * num_epochs), int(4 * num_epochs)], gamma=0.25)

num_forward_pass = 10
batch_size = 1000
num_batches = int((len(t)-num_forward_pass)/batch_size)

print("number of batches")
print(num_batches)

total_epochs = int(5.5*num_epochs)
Loss_array = []
for epoch in range(total_epochs):

    if epoch % int(total_epochs/20) == 0:
      print("Percentage Completed: " + str(epoch/total_epochs*100) + "%")
    if epoch == int(total_epochs*0.99):
      print("Almost Done. Percent Completed = " + str(epoch/total_epochs*100) + "%")
    for batch_index in range(num_batches-1):
        y = ((2*torch.rand(batch_size) - 1)*2.5).to(device)
        dydt = ((2*torch.rand(batch_size) - 1)*2.5).to(device)
        force = force_train[batch_index*batch_size:(batch_index*batch_size + len(y) + num_forward_pass)].to(device)

        if epoch < num_epochs :
            input = torch.stack((y, dydt, force[:-num_forward_pass]), dim=1).double()
            predictions = neural_solution(input)

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            dy_dt_comp = (predictions[:, 0] - input[:, 0]) / delta_t
            d2y_dt2_comp = (predictions[:, 1] - input[:, 1]) / delta_t
            force_comp = (d2y_dt2_comp + predictions[:, 1] + 4 * predictions[:, 0]).double()
            loss = cost_function(force_comp, force[1:-(num_forward_pass-1)]) + cost_function(dy_dt_comp, predictions[:, 1])

        elif epoch < 3 * num_epochs:
            input = torch.stack((y, dydt, force[:-num_forward_pass]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_0 = neural_solution(input)
            input_1 = torch.stack((predictions_0[:, 0], predictions_0[:, 1], force[1:-(num_forward_pass - 1)]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_1 = neural_solution(input_1)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            dy_dt_comp = (predictions_1[:, 0] - input[:, 0]) / (2 * delta_t)
            d2y_dt2_comp = (predictions_1[:, 1] - input[:, 1]) / (2 * delta_t)
            force_comp = (d2y_dt2_comp + predictions_0[:, 1] + 4 * predictions_0[:, 0]).double()
            loss = cost_function(force_comp, force[1:-(num_forward_pass - 1)]) + cost_function(dy_dt_comp, predictions_0[:, 1])
        
        else:
            input_0 = torch.stack((y, dydt, force[:-num_forward_pass]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_0 = neural_solution(input_0)
            input_1 = torch.stack((predictions_0[:, 0], predictions_0[:, 1], force[1:-(num_forward_pass - 1)]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_1 = neural_solution(input_1)
            input_2 = torch.stack((predictions_1[:, 0], predictions_1[:, 1], force[2:-(num_forward_pass - 2)]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_2 = neural_solution(input_2)
            input_3 = torch.stack((predictions_2[:, 0], predictions_2[:, 1], force[3:-(num_forward_pass - 3)]), dim=1).double()
            predictions_3 = neural_solution(input_3)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            dy_dt_comp = (-1/12 * predictions_3[:, 0] + 4/3 * predictions_2[:, 0] - 5/2 * predictions_1[:, 0] + 4/3 * predictions_0[:, 0] - 1/12 * y) / delta_t
            d2y_dt2_comp = (-1/12 * predictions_3[:, 1] + 4/3 * predictions_2[:, 1] - 5/2 * predictions_1[:, 1] + 4/3 * predictions_0[:, 1] - 1/12 * dydt) / delta_t
            force_comp = (d2y_dt2_comp + predictions_2[:, 1] + 4 * predictions_2[:, 0]).double()
            loss = cost_function(force_comp, force[2:-(num_forward_pass - 2)]) + cost_function(dy_dt_comp, predictions_2[:, 1])


        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    Loss_array.append(loss.item())
    scheduler.step()


y_pred = [0]
dy_dt_pred = [0.2]
for i, time in enumerate(t[1:]):
    input_test = torch.tensor([[y_pred[i - 1], dy_dt_pred[i - 1], force_train[i - 1]]]).double().to(device)  # Convert to double precision
    y_next = neural_solution(input_test)

    with torch.no_grad():
        y_pred.append(y_next[0, 0].item())
        dy_dt_pred.append(y_next[0, 1].item())

plt.plot(Loss_array)
plt.show()

plt.plot(t, y_pred, label="Neural Network Prediction")
plt.plot(t, soln.T[0], label="ODEint - Ground Truth")
plt.title("Training Data Comparison")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(np.log(Loss_array))
plt.show()

# Testing the function:

# Define the test function
def test_function(t):
    return (4 * np.sin(t**1.1/4) * np.exp(-0.02 * t) * (t > 35))* (t<75) + (t>100)*np.sin(2*t/5)*np.sin(1.2*t/4) * (t<120)

def dY_dt(t,Y):
  x,v = Y
  Y_dot = [v, test_function(t) - v - 4*x]
  return Y_dot

S0 = [-0.2,0.7]

#t = np.linspace(0,150,20000)
soln_test = odeint(dY_dt, y0 = S0, t = t, tfirst = True)
y_true =soln_test.T[0] 
force_test = torch.tensor(test_function(t))


y_pred = [-0.2]
dy_dt_pred = [0.7]
for i, time in enumerate(t[1:]):
  #input_test = torch.tensor([[y_pred[i-1], dy_dt_pred[i-1], force_test[i-1]]]).float().to(device)
  input_test = torch.tensor([[y_pred[i - 1], dy_dt_pred[i - 1], force_test[i - 1]]]).double().to(device)
  y_next = neural_solution(input_test)

  with torch.no_grad():
    y_pred.append(y_next[0, 0].item())
    dy_dt_pred.append(y_next[0, 1].item())


plt.plot(t, y_true, label = "ODEint")
plt.plot(t,y_pred, label = "Predicted")
plt.title("Test Function y(t)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.plot(t,y_pred, label = "Predicted")
plt.title("Test Function y(t)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.plot(t, y_true, label = "ODEint")
plt.title("Test Function y(t)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.plot(t, soln_test.T[1] , label = "")
plt.plot(t,dy_dt_pred, label = "Predicted")
plt.title("Test Function dy(t)/dt")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.plot(t,dy_dt_pred, label = "Predicted")
plt.title("Test Function dy(t)/dt")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.plot(t, soln_test.T[1], label = "ODEint")
plt.title("Test Function dy(t)/dt")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I didn't get the desired result so i used a centered difference scheme and then i used a higher point stencil for greater accuracy but got unexpected results.

I also tried to train with a simpler loss for a first few epochs and then increased complexity with higher epochs.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the 5 point stencil implementation like this and it did not work as expected even though I thought it would solve the issue:

```
   else:
        input_0 = torch.stack((y, dydt, force[:-num_forward_pass]), dim=1).double()
        predictions_0 = neural_solution(input_0)
        input_1 = torch.stack((predictions_0[:, 0], predictions_0[:, 1], force[1:-(num_forward_pass - 1)]), dim=1).double()
        predictions_1 = neural_solution(input_1)
        input_2 = torch.stack((predictions_1[:, 0], predictions_1[:, 1], force[2:-(num_forward_pass - 2)]), dim=1).double()
        predictions_2 = neural_solution(input_2)
        input_3 = torch.stack((predictions_2[:, 0], predictions_2[:, 1], force[3:-(num_forward_pass - 3)]), dim=1).double()
        predictions_3 = neural_solution(input_3)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        dy_dt_comp = (-1 * predictions_3[:, 0] + 8 * predictions_2[:, 0] + 0 * predictions_1[:, 0] - 8 * predictions_0[:, 0] + 1 * y) / (12*delta_t)
        d2y_dt2_comp = (-1 * predictions_3[:, 1] + 8 * predictions_2[:, 1] + 0 * predictions_1[:, 1] - 8 * predictions_0[:, 1] + 1 * dydt) / (12*delta_t)
        force_comp = (d2y_dt2_comp + predictions_1[:, 1] + 4 * predictions_1[:, 0]).double()
        loss = cost_function(force_comp, force[2:-(num_forward_pass - 2)]) + cost_function(dy_dt_comp, predictions_1[:, 1])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. If you'd like to add more information relating to the question, edit the original post to provide any extra information.